# Firebase Realtime Database persistance clarification needed

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

For an Android client with Firebase Realtime Database persistence enabled, is it true that there will be no Firebase downloads each time I close and re-open the app, assuming there have been no changes to the database?

Furthermore, with persistence enabled, each time an app is re-opened, is it true that Firebase will only download the changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes to both, if I may quote the documentation :

> By enabling persistence, any data that we sync while online will be
>   persisted to disk and available offline, even when we restart the app.
>   This means our app will work as it would online using the local data
>   stored in the cache. Listener callbacks will continue to fire for
>   local updates.

[Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

It's just amazing you could do this with one line of code, and I've been integrating offline capabilities to all the projects I've been developing lately, it works like a charm and less headache for us developers.

**EDIT:**

Provided that disk persistence is enabled and it isn't the first launch of the app, I can confirm that Firebase does not re-download the whole database again. When I was first implementing the persistence storage.I was monitoring the network usage of my app using Android studio, in first launch I could see a considerable usage of network resources, then  I restarted the app and there was no activity in the network usage monitor.

Then I added few Strings to the database via Firebase console and monitored the usage when I restart the app and I could see a small network usage in the monitor, which I would define as just downloading the changes I did to my database and my app was synced with the changes instantly.

Comment: thanks @RamithDR.  I did see this in the documentation, but since this is with respect to going offline, I don't think it is clear that "even when we restart the app", that Firebase will or will not re-download the database.  Do you have personal experience that shows that, even in the case of normal online usage, after restarts, Firebase does not re-download the database?