# Firebase Realtime Database maximum cache size in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

What is the maximum Firebase Realtime Database cache size for an Android client?  Is it limited by Firebase or Android?

Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) says:

> By default, 10MB of previously synced data will be cached. This should be enough for most applications. If the cache outgrows its configured size, the Firebase Realtime Database will purge data that has been used least recently. Data that is kept in sync, will not be purged from the cache

But the final sentence there (with it's oddly placed comma) makes the paragraph unclear to me.  Is there a 10MB limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit of 10MB is one that comes from the Firebase SDK.

The last lines refers to data from locations on which you've called [`ref.keepSynced(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache). These locations will not be evicted from the cache.

The write queue (any local write operations that are not yet synchronized with the server) is not part of the 10MB limit.

So it is possible that the persistent cache may require a bit more than 10MB. In general that should be limited though.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen, but it is still not clear to me what the 10MB limit is, if the cache can be more than 10MB.  What is limited to 10MB?

Comment: We try to keep a limit of 10MB on the cache size. There are just some reasons why the cache might grow beyond that. In normal operation this should not affect your app, so I recommend not spending too much time on the exact details of when this may happen.

Comment: this point is important to me, I may have a large database, sorry to keep pushing.  It seems to me that the cache size could be entirely determined by the size of the nodes of the database that I am synchronizing.  If I'm trying to synchronize 100MB, then would Firebase allow the cache to go to 100MB? 1GB?   I'm just trying to understand the limit.

Comment: Any data you are actively syncing (by having an active listener or by calling keepSynced() on it) will always be stored in the cache.  We only prune data when it's not being used.  So if you sync 1GB of data, your cache will be 1GB.  Also, your app will be super slow and crashing due to out-of-memory errors if you sync 1GB.

The 10MB limit is basically for "recently used" data that we automatically keep in cache so it's available offline.

Keep in mind that 10MB of JSON data is actually quite a lot, and is way more than most applications synchronize to the device.

Comment: thanks @Michael Lehenbauer.  I may be straying from the original question (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211019/firebase-realtime-database-persistance-clarification-needed)) but will the cache survive app restarts?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase it to 100 mb using this
code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(100000000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add some documentation or explanation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.